# How to use etcd3 nodejs client for differnt port than standard?

Tags: node.js, grpc, etcd, etcd3

I am using https://github.com/microsoft/etcd3 for etcd3 NodeJS client, but it is by default taking default port 2379 or 2380 for gRPC. But I am running multiple etcd docker container instances. How to create multiple clients based on multiple ports.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/stianeikeland/node-etcd | https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/master/Documentation/op-guide/configuration.md . Found 2 resources, examples also included. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Well, thanks for your reply. The first link is about version2 I tried that at first place and about second link, I don't find info about node.js client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can provide a single or array of hosts when you construct the client. See the following for `hosts` and a slightly more involved reference for configuring `grpcOptions`:

https://microsoft.github.io/etcd3/interfaces/ioptions.html#hosts

https://microsoft.github.io/etcd3/interfaces/ioptions.html#grpcoptions

So use values other than `localhost` and `2379`:

```js
const client = new Etcd3(options = { hosts: '127.0.0.1:2379' });
```